# MYSQL script with database selection from query

Tags: mysql, database, sql-scripts

Is there any way to write a Mysql script with a parameter for "USE" steatment?

I tried this:

```
SET @test=(SELECT dbname FROM dblist WHERE active>0);
USE @test;
ALTER ...
```

But it doesn't work.

My goal is to change/alter with my script a particular database selected by a query.

Comment: Have you looked at https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,27979,30437? I am not sure the USE statement is supported as dynamic SQL, but worth a try...

Comment: You might rethink this and fully qualify your table names with the db ie dbname.tablename

Comment: @P.Salmon I can use fullyq. names but the first part (db name) is still stored in another database. Consider that in dblist I have all companies of a ERP software and I want to apply the script only on the "active" company, it cannot be hardcoded in the script.